# How to replace a number from a text which is not appended to a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to replace the number 123 from the below string, but the challenge I am facing is - everytime I replace it, then the number i.e, 1 from name "Xyz1" also got changed. Below is a sample code which I already tried:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class NumberToString
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String str = "Hello Xyz1, your id is 123";
        // str = str.replaceAll("[0-9]","idNew");
        // str = str.replaceAll("\\d","idNew");
        // str = str.replaceAll("\\d+","idNew");
        str = str.replaceAll("(?>-?\\d+(?:[\\./]\\d+)?)","idNew");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Output of the above code is:
Hello XyzidNew, your id is idNew

But, the output which I need is:
Hello Xyz1, your id is idNew

Comment: How many numbers may `Xyz1` contain and how long will the id be?

Comment: Use a word boundary, `"(?>-?\\b\\d+(?:[\\./]\\d+)?)\\b"` or a simpler `"-?\\b\\d+(?:[./]\\d+)?\\b"`

Comment: Xyz1 can contain upto 7 numbers and id would be of max length of 10.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the regular expression `\d+$`, you will get the expected output. Example:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String str = "Hello Xyz1, your id is 123";
    str = str.replaceAll("\\d+$","idNew");
    System.out.println(str);
    // Variation without the end of line boundary matcher
    System.out.println("Hello Xyz1, your id is 123.".replaceAll("\\b\\d+(?![0-9])","idNew"));
}
```

`\d+$` - this regular expression matches multiple digits, followed by the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. I just tried and it is working for this scenario, but let say if we add a new string after 123, then in that case whole regex fails. Any suggestions ??

Comment: @PraveenKishor check the variation in the updated answer which does not use the end of line boundary matcher.